Installing SSL + HTTPS using a reverse proxy like caddy on Android to enable secure connections for my server Emby
I want to install a reverse proxy useful because I want to put online my emby server on top of Android 14 using https on port 8920.
I have fixed the 443 error in this way :
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip $(which caddy)

solution taken from here :
Caddy "listen tcp :443: bind: permission denied"
and I removed the parameter “–disable-redirects” from the Caddyfile.
now I run caddy with this command :
/data $ sudo caddy run -c /data/Caddyfile

the situation seems to be better,but caddy seems to does still run for some reason,but I don’t understand why :
https://ibb.co/r6jw9Ss
https://ibb.co/LrmDBy1
I don’t see errors,it should work,but when I open my website,at address :
https://ziomario.ns0.it:8920

it says : unable to connect. why ?
In the emby control panel I see :
Lan Access = http://192.168.1.7:8096 (and it works)
Wan Access = https://ziomario.ns0.it:8920 (and it does not work)

In Network settings I chosen :
LAN networks = empty
local IP address = empty

http local port = 8096
https local port = 8920

http public port = 8096
https public port = 8920

external domain = ziomario.ns0.it
secure connection mode = managed by the reverse proxy.

On my router I have opened ports : 8096,8920,443,80 in TCP and UDP mode…
If you want to read the full story,I've opened a thread here :
https://caddy.community/t/installing-ssl-https-using-a-reverse-proxy-like-caddy-on-android/25182
But it seems to be hard to be able to accomplish this task,so I took the decision to ask here,too,because I know that this place is full of qualified experts in every tech field.
PS : actually this is my Caddyfile :
nano /data/Caddyfile :

ziomario.ns0.it {
               encode
               reverse_proxy 192.168.1.7:8096
}


No one wants to help again here ?
The precise error that I get right now is :
ERROR : http log error dial tcp 192.168.1.6:8096: connect : connection refused. request remote ip 83.147.52.49 remote port 45394 client IP = 83.147.52.49 proto HTTP/1.1 method GET host ziomario.ns0.it url gitlab-ci.yml headers user-agent go-http-client/1.1 accept encoding gzip tls resumed false version 772 cipher_suite 4867 proto server name ziomario.ns0.it duration 0.0015 status 502 err_id 36k92p912 err_trace reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy go:1269)

Also posted on Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/258023/44325
